# How to get the pid of a process that is run through ssh

Tags: linux, ssh, process

Lets say I have two servers, server1 & server2

In server 1, i do `ssh root@server2 "some_command"`

How do I find the pid of this `some_command` from server1?

Comment: You don't because the process runs on server2. You can ssh to server2 from server1.

Comment: You could try `ssh root@server2 "ps -ef" | grep whatever_is_suitable_to_identify_the_command`. There is no guarantee that you will catch a single process; there might be other processes whose command line corresponds to this string.

Comment: Normally, you could `ssh root@server2 "some_other_command"` from another shell running in some other terminal emulator

Answer (score 1):

```
ssh user@server2 'echo "$$" | tee some_command.pid && exec some_command'
```

Would output the PID of the shell process that's interpreting that code, save a copy in the  `some_command.pid` file in the home directory of `user` and then that same process (not a child process), so with the same PID would execute `some_command`.

Later, you can do `ssh user@server2 'cat some_command.pid'` to retrieve that PID (whether there are still processes running that `some_command` or not and whether one of those processes is the one with that same PID or not and whether the process that was running that shell and then `some_command` is still running `some_command` or not).

Answer (score 0):

You can find the pid of your command from server1 by using the below command:

```
ssh root@server2 "some_command && ps -ef|grep some_command"
```

Comment: Which will output the pids of `some_command` *and* `grep`

Answer (score 0):

You could also do:

```
ssh user@server2 'some_command & echo "$!" '
```

Edited as per Stéphane Chazelas, indeed when I checked I did not realize that two separate commands will not echo back the PID. It works in this incarnation. Thanks.

Comment: ITYM `'some_command & echo "$!"'`.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Thank you for the correction.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is:

```
ssh user@server2 'pidof some_command'
```

As you do not mention what *nix you are on, I do not know whether you have access to that command.
I know it is al the least available on Debian and derivatives and RedHat and derivatives...

Comment: From https://linuxize.com/post/pidof-command-in-linux/ : 

pidof is a command-line utility that allows you to find the process ID of a running program.

...

There are different implementations of pidof for Red Hat and Debian based distributions. On Red Hat distributions, the pidof command is a part of the procps-ng package, while on Debian, it is part of sysvinit-utils. ...

The syntax for the pidof command is as follows:

`pidof [OPTIONS] PROGRAM_NAME`